# Enter fires the form submit

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a `div` (nice gif displayed as-if it's a button), on that `div` is a piece of JavaScript that handles the ENTER as-if it's a click `$(this).click()`. The click does its own thing.

In Firefox, it all works perfectly: the user presses the enter on the button and the click is fired.
In IE, the form is submitted not the `click()`

Comment: How are you ensuring that the focus is on the div when the enter button is clicked?

Comment: You should post the relevant code here :)

Answer (score 3):

This is a handy dandy jQuery function I use to get around this.

```
$(formSelector).find('input, select').keypress(function (event) {

    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(buttonSelector).click().focus();

        return false;
    }
});
```

`formSelector` is just a variable holding the `#FormId`, and `buttonSelector` is a variable holding the button I want to be clicked. so in your case, it would be: `#IdOfYourDivToClick`.

Comment: Can I ask why you run `click()` before `focus()`?

Comment: no real reason, the focus() is was an after thought b/c i wanted the button highlighting to happen.

Answer (score 0):

In IE, the default behavior of the enter key on an input element (button type) is a form submit (most of the time).

You can try to capture the keydown event and check for enter key; if it is then run `event.preventDefault()`.

Take a look at:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.preventDefault

If you post some code, I can help you by modifying your code. Post your HTML and relevant JavaScript.